# Redirect to previous action after login

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have an action **addFavorite** witch only AUTHENTICATED user can access . When user is anonymous, he will be redirected to login form. So I would like the user to be redirected to this action after connection.
Right now he is redirected to default path

**security.yml**

```
        main:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider:  main
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /
            target_path_parameter:          _target_path
            use_referer:         true
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path:   fos_user_security_logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key:    %secret%
```

**actionController:**

```
    public function addFavoriteAction(Travel $travel, Request $request)
    {

    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'GET') {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $nbFav = $em->getRepository('ProjectTravelBundle:Favorite')->findOneBy(array('user' =>$user, 'travel' =>$travel));

    if(!$nbFav)
    { 
        $favorite = new Favorite();     
        $favorite->setUser($user);
        $favorite->setTravel($travel);

        $em->persist($favorite);
        $em->flush();
    }
    }
    $referer = $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');
    return $this->redirect($referer);
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand your code. But you can do this way.When user comes to your site save the path at session or database before sending him login page.After login check your session or database if there is a value of his previous link then redirect him to that link else redirect him to default controller.

Comment: you can add an additional variable to be passed via GET method when redirecting to the login page, after login you can extract the value from the variable and redirect the user back to the original page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-success), the user is automatically redirected to the page they were trying to access.  So if they were on the *addFavorite* route already while not authenticated, they would be logged in and sent right back to it.

You can also set it manually in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="your_route_name_goes_here" />
```